# Duplicate tags [european] [eu]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

"european" (currently 7 questions) and "eu" (currently 10 questions) are duplicate tags. "European" should be made a synonym of "eu".

Answer (score 0):

Done.

I created a tag synonym, so anybody who files a question with [eu](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) will now automatically have it switched to [european](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european). This also applies retroactively to existing questions.

Thanks for your help identifying tags on the site--I know we've got a lot that are duplicates, or otherwise don't fit well [within our guidelines](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), and getting those cleaned up is a great help to improving the quality and searchability of the site.